# How to split array values to new array?

Tags: php, arrays

how to split received values of an array into a new array?

so from this:

```
[["+","+","+"],["-","+","+"],["*","+","+"],["\/","+","+"],
```

to this:

```
["+"],["+"],["+"],["-"],["+"],["+"],["*"],["+"],["+"],
```

can someone help me?

Comment: With a loop or array_merge.

Comment: This isn't a split but a flattening.

Comment: thank you verry much @LightnessRacesinOrbit! this fixed my problem

Comment: @vdhmartijn: I have my moments

Comment: you can use regular expression :

    $str ='[["Z","A","B"],["-","+","+"],["*","+","+"],["\/","+","+"],';
    preg_match_all("/[\"|']([^\]\[\"]+)[\"|']/i", $str, $matches);

$matches[1] is your new array,

    print_r($matches[1]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten your array by looping through it

```
$aFlattened = array();
foreach($aOriginalArray AS $aOperators){
   $aFlattened = array_merge($aFlattened, $aOperators);
}
```

Comment: is there also a way to put al flattened values into new arrays?

Comment: @vdhmartijn `array_map` them